# Miglayout error:NoClassDefFoundError: net/miginfocom/layout/ComponentWrapper netbeans miglayout

Tags: java, miglayout

this miglayout error is not letting me run the application, if anyone could help me resolve it I would be grateful, the phrase that appears is the one in the title therefore an execution error.

I don't know if it interferes but I use netbens.

The objective is for the application to run but unfortunately it ends up with this error where it is impossible to run the application. I would like to fix it

Comment: I don't know enough about NetBeans to give you a definitive answer, but this is a problem with your classpath at runtime, so try to check that please - you need to know where this class "comes from" (which JAR file) and then add that JAR file to your classpath.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.